# Wordpress Call to undefined function

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I can't access my function.

I'm creating an WordPress plugin and I need the post's id to get data from the database.

So this is the setup to create a metabox:

```
$CMB_userName = get_post_meta( get_the_post_id(), 'CMB-user-metabox', true );
if (isset($CMB_userName)){
    $UMB = new userMetaBox();
    $UMB->setName($CMB_userName);   
    $UMB->init();
}
```

The `setName()` function creates the name of the metabox. A user sets this and get's saved in the databse. Now to get the data from the database I use the function `get_post_meta`. This requires an ID.

To get the ID I used a function:

```
public function get_the_post_id() {
    if( isset($_GET['post']) ) {
        $post_id = absint( isset($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : ( isset($_POST['post_ID']) ? $_POST['post_ID'] : 0 ) );
        $post = $post_id != 0 ? get_post( $post_id ) : false; // Post Object, like in the Theme loop
        return $post;

    }
}
```

But when I run it the following error occurs

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_post_id() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/plugin/wp-content/plugins/custom_metaBox/custom-meta-box.php on line 32`

Can someone see where it's failing?

Comment: WordPress already has a function which practically does the same as your `get_the_post_id()`, called `get_the_ID()` why not use that?

Comment: Yeah tried that but turns up empty for some reason. I think it might because this is outside the loop

Comment: Also, your function has a `public` declaration which would suggest it's part of an object, which would mean you need to access it as an object like `$obj->get_the_post_id()`, but it's not clear from your provided code

Comment: Your comment is valid. So I changed it to: `$CMB_userName = get_post_meta( $UMB->get_the_post_id(), 'CMB-user-metabox', true );` but now it doesn't show the metabox and no error for that matter. I do have the debug enabled. Any thoughts?

Comment: Got it.... The functions returns the entire post and I needed only the ID. Your comment about the `$obj->get_the_post_id` did pushed me into the right direction.